# Visual Studio 2015 not showing project folder content

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, atlassian-sourcetree

Fixed by Repairing the VS2015 from the setup file.

---

> I've added a VS 2013 project to Visual Studio 2015. It compiles and
>   runs as expected, but in Solution Explore i can't see the content of
>   the folders.
>
> I've tried deleting the folders and adding them again, but it didn't
>   work.
>
> Any ideas? I also use SourceTree for the project, but i don't think
>   it's relevant.
>
> [![enter image description here][1]][1]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhm3B.png
>
> Edit 1: Please note that this issues happens to all the folders in the
>   project (Resourfes, Themes, Sources)
>
> 1.) The files exist and are visible in Windows Explorer
>
> 2.) Deleting and adding the folder again, or the individual files in a newly  created folder does not change the situation.
>
> 3.)  csproj has the files that are not show in the folders :
>
> ```
>      <ItemGroup>
>     <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </ApplicationDefinition>
>     <Compile Include="Sources\LoginViewModel.cs" />
>     <Compile Include="Sources\RelayCommand.cs" />
>     <Compile Include="Sources\ViewModel.cs" />
>     <Compile Include="Login.xaml.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>Login.xaml</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="WrongPassword.xaml.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>WrongPassword.xaml</DependentUpon>
>     </Compile>
>     <Page Include="MainWindow.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </Page>
>     <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
>       <SubType>Code</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Compile Include="MainWindow.xaml.cs">
>       <DependentUpon>MainWindow.xaml</DependentUpon>
>       <SubType>Code</SubType>
>     </Compile>
>     <Page Include="Resources\Icons.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </Page>
>     <Page Include="Themes\Metro\Dark\MetroDark.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </Page>
>     <Page Include="Themes\Metro\Dark\MetroDark.MSControls.Toolkit.Implicit.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </Page>
>     <Page Include="Themes\Metro\Dark\Styles.Shared.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </Page>
>     <Page Include="Themes\Metro\Dark\Styles.WPF.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </Page>
>     <Page Include="Themes\Metro\Dark\Theme.Colors.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </Page>
>     <Page Include="Themes\Metro\Light\Metro.MSControls.Core.Implicit.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </Page>
>     <Page Include="Themes\Metro\Light\Metro.MSControls.Toolkit.Implicit.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </Page>
>     <Page Include="Themes\Metro\Light\Styles.Shared.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </Page>
>     <Page Include="Themes\Metro\Light\Styles.WPF.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </Page>
>     <Page Include="Themes\Metro\Light\Theme.Colors.xaml">
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>     </Page>
>     <Page Include="Login.xaml">
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>     </Page>
>     <Page Include="WrongPassword.xaml">
>       <SubType>Designer</SubType>
>       <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
>     </Page>
>   </ItemGroup>
> ```

Comment: Look inside `csproj` file and post here related `ItemGroup` (for that `Sources` folder).

Comment: There is a button to show 'hidden' files in the solution explorer. Click it, select the files you are interested in and select 'include in project' from the context menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by Repairing the VS2015 from the setup file.

Answer (score 9):

After adding the file to the correct folder. Click on the Show all Files option, include the file in the project. And that's it

Answer (score 7):

The files are probably not listed in the solution. Try right-clicking the folder in VS, selecting 'Open in File Explorer', then dragging the contents onto the folder in VS. This should add them to the .sln file.

Answer (score 2):

Faced this problem with VS 2015 Community Edition and identified the problem happened due to one of the extensions ([Mexedge Stylesheet extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b6dd8050-77fa-4dba-998f-dabdd255d96d) in my case). After disabling this extension and restarting, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Repair of installation did not help. Uninstallation and new installation did the work.

Answer (score 0):

If it's converted, then the file should be there. Maybe the solution file refreshed and skipped the reference of this folder.

Try these steps:

1. Right-click on the solution and unload it, then edit the solution (right-click and edit the solution), check the file's path defined and determine if it's correct or not.
2. Navigate to the project directory and check files are there or not. If the files are there then: refresh the solution and click to show the hidden files, and if you see those file, then add to the solution.
3. If the files are not in the directory, add the existing file to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem, but only on one particular project, where I couldn't see files in folders.  If I opened another project, I could see its files that were in folders, so I knew I didn't have a Visual Studio-wide problem.  So then I just rebuilt my project. Steps:

1. Shut down Visual Studio.
2. Moved my project to another folder (so I could re-create my project with its old name)
3. Launched VS.  Created another project like my last one, including all pages and folders.
4. Copied my old pages from my old Explorer folder on top of the pages in my new project's Explorer folder (Visual Studio recognizes the changes and asks you if you want to reload the content - say "Yes to All").
5. Copy the classes from the old Explorer folder to the new one.
6. In VS, in the Solution Explorer, right-click the folder you created there that represents the Explorer one you copied classes to in step 5, select "Add Existing Item..." and highlight all the classes (Ctrl+A, or hold Ctrl and click the mouse on the files) and click Add.

You should be back where the Solution Explorer is able to show your files again.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2015 We have new feature Hide Folder/Unhide folders. some times people by unintesitionally press it. you can get it back, right click the on solution and click on unhide option from the list as shown in picture below.

[image]